# yum install simplescreenrecorder (No package simplescreenrecorder available.)

Tags: linux, yum, centos-7

```
yum install simplescreenrecorder
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos-hn.viettelidc.com.vn
 * extras: centos-hcm.viettelidc.com.vn
 * updates: mirrors.nhanhoa.com
No package simplescreenrecorder available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I amd trying to install simplescreenrecorder but it fails

Answer (score 7):

simplescreenrecorder is not available in the standard CentOS repos. You can get it from [li.nux.ro](http://li.nux.ro).

```
# yum install epel-release
# rpm -Uvh http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-5.el7.nux.noarch.rpm
```

then

```
# yum install simplescreenrecorder
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

nano /etc/yum.repos.d/atrpm.repo

[atrpms]
name=Fedora Core $releasever - $basearch - ATrpms
baseurl=http://dl.atrpms.net/el$releasever-$basearch/atrpms/stable
gpgkey=http://ATrpms.net/RPM-GPG-KEY.atrpms
gpgcheck=1

Answer (score -1):

Is this CentOS 7 or 6?

You have to install EPEL from a separate Repository.

Script Save As -> simplescreenrecorder.sh 
using nano or vi command
To Run in your Present working Directory type

sh simplescreenrecorder.sh

This will execute your Script / GitHub Is good as well to save scripts.
Or USB Key in a jewelry box in a safe.

Present Working Directory

pwd

cd /tmp

Always verify the link to download use lynx

yum -y install lynx

wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-10.noarch.rpm

yum -y install epel-release-7-10.noarch.rpm

OR

rpm -Uvh epel-release-7-10.noarch.rpm

Not always verify

ls *.rpm

or

ls -lha

Or try from source using the source file .tarball 
make, make install, ./configure
Try the Readme Docs from the main site

Oh by the looks of it is not in that repo  its in ATRPM.REPO
Read This:

https://www.tecmint.com/screencasting-with-simple-screen-recorder-in-linux/

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.